# Content Security Policy: contradict error message

Tags: content-security-policy

> Refused to load media from
>   'https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-public-bucket/file.txt'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "media-src https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-public-bucket
>   https://my-private-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com".

How can it be? I can load for example `https://my-private-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/file.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the slash, CSP is reading the first directive as allowing a specific file, not a directory; usually this would be for something like `https://s3.amazonaws.com/file.js`.

The second directive however, as it's a root domain, is being read as allowing the entire domain (including subdomain).

It all depends on exactly how specific you want to be, CSP allows a lot of flexibility. You can specify keywords, exact resources down to the file name, directories or whole domains. Common practice tends to be whitelisting whole domains but if you're sure you won't need it, it can't hurt to be a little specific (until it does).

You can read up a bit more on it [here in the W3 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#framework-directive-source-list).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding `/` to the problematic resource, but it looks strange - why does the second directive allow media without stash?